# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении, если да, то почему?
*Мы разместились в маленькой комнате(,) в подвале.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы разместились в маленькой комнате, **в подвале**. В этом предложении идет уточнение. Мы (**что сделали?**) разместились (**где?**) в маленькой комнате (**где комната?**), в подвале.

Comment: Ответ неверен. Запятая здесь факультативна.

Comment: @Nektoid хоть она и факультативна, но никто не отменял такого варианта. Понятное дело, что автор может сам решить, где поставить знак препинания и хочет ли он обозначить этим уточнение местоположения.

Comment: Почему неверен? Мы разместились в маленькой кОмнате, в подвАле.  Предложение удобно прочитать именно с уточнением. Вариант: "Мы разместились // в маленькой комнате в подвАле"  хуже. При неоднородные отношениях такая структура не так удобна для чтения. Тогда хотя бы так: РазместИлись мы // в маленькой комнате в подвале. Тогда хотя бы ясно, как читать.

Comment: @ven2ra на этом форуме принято сперва давать в ответе возможные варианты (если варианты есть) и лишь потом говорить, какой считаете правильным именно вы. Иначе ответ неверен, потому что неполон.

Comment: @Nektoid проведя морфологический разбор предложения, я наглядным путем показал, как стоит проверять предложение и нужна ли запятая.

Comment: @Sharon ну, во-первых, формально подвал больше комнаты, поэтому уточнение, то есть переход от более общего к более частному, тут звучит нелепо. "Мы разместились в подвале, в маленькой комнате" -- другое дело. Во-вторых, вы же сами отстаивали вариативность: https://clck.ru/hCGS2

Comment: @ven2ra ещё раз: ответ ваш неверен, потому что неполон, указывает лишь один вариант как единственный. В этом вопросе (https://clck.ru/hCGVe) я дал ссылку на соответствующее правило Розенталя.

Comment: @Nektoid "Переходы" разные бывают, затем вы "художку"  ограничиваете в самовыражении? ;))  Я, кстати,  считаю, что, задавая структуру, автор обычно подсказывает нам и знаки препинания (то есть семантику он уже выбрал). Разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что здесь дело, собственно, не в запятой, а в **смысле** вымученного предложения.
Невозможно разместиться **одновременно** и в комнате, и в подвале (если нет сопутствующего, разъяснительного контекста).

Первый вариант
Большущий подвал имеет несколько помещений (пусть — комнат), тогда можно сказать так:
*Мы разместились в маленькой комнате подвала.*
Или:
*Мы разместились в подвале, в маленькой комнате.*

Второй вариант
Каждая из комнат в доме имеет отдельный вход в подвал. Тогда так:
*Мы разместились в подвале маленькой комнаты.*

Comment: Ничего "вымученного" я в предложении не вижу.  Выглядит оно естественно, а контекста у нас нет. Так что все "пространственные фантазии" смотрятся в данном случае  не у места. Уточнение может восприниматься как дополнительная информация, только и всего. Главное сообщение —  это "маленькую комнату", а тема подвала упоминается попутно (= кстати, комната расположена в подвале).